# Moving an article to another Site in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I am to build a new site and have to move the old articles to this new sharepoint site., so that the old Wiki that we have is to be scrapped.

A document can be opened in an explorer and the documents can be moved. But here., 
the old site has a list and that list has articles.

I have to move those to the new site as articles and not as a list. Is there any way to do it?